# Arithmetic-Geometric progression general integral formula

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

I'm solving Arithmetic-Geometric progression. It's rules:
$$
k(x)\in Z, \forall{x}\\
f(0)=k(0)\\
q(x) > 0, \forall{x}\\
f(x)=f(x-1)\frac{q(x)}{q(x-1)}+k(x)-k(x-1)
$$
I got the general formula:
$$
f(x)=k(x)+q(x)\cdot\lim_{n->0}{\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{x}{d}-1}k(nd)\cdot(\frac{1}{q(nd)}-\frac{1}{q(nd+d)})}\\
f(x)=k(x)+q(x)\cdot\lim_{n->0}{\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{x}{d}-1}\frac{k(nd)\cdot q\prime(nd)}{q(nd)\cdot q(nd+d)}}\\
$$
And I thought it was:
$$
f(x)=k(x)+q(x)\cdot\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{k(t)\cdot q\prime(t)}{q^{2}(t)}\cdot dt}
$$
But it's not. It's valid for $\forall x, |x|<\epsilon$.
I thought `q(nd+d)` would be a `q(t)` under integral. I think it was a mistake.
By the way, I've found another formula for `k(x)` that works fine (as I think):
$$
k(x)=f(x)+\lim_{d->0}{\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{x}{d}-1}{f(nd)\cdot(1-\frac{q(nd+d)}{q(nd)})}}\\
k(x)=f(x)-\lim_{d->0}{\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{x}{d}-1}{\frac{f(nd)\cdot(q(nd+d)-q(nd))\cdot d}{q(nd)\cdot d}}}\\
\lim_{d->0}{\frac{q(t+d)-q(t)}{d}}=q\prime(t)\\
k(x)=f(x)-\lim_{d->0}{\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{x}{d}-1}{\frac{f(nd)\cdot q\prime(nd)\cdot d}{q(nd)}}}\\
k(x)=f(x)-\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{f(t)\cdot q\prime(t)}{q(t)}\cdot dt}
$$
Help me find the `f(x)` formula.

Comment: Help me find my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two classic functions thus
$$
\forall d>0, d \in Z, \forall x\in Z\\
\frac{q(x+d)}{q(x)}=q^{d}, q>0 \\
k(x+d)-k(x)=k\cdot d
$$
Now, I'll find the general formula.
$$
f(x)=f(x-d)\cdot \frac{q(x)}{q(x-d)}+k(x)-k(x-d)=\\
=q^d\cdot f(x-d)+kd\\
Substitution:\\
f(x)=(f(x-2d)⋅q^{d}+kd)⋅q^{d}+kd=\\
=f(x-2d)⋅q^{2d}+kd(1+q^{d})=\\
=(f(x-3d)⋅q^{d}+kd)⋅q^{2d}+kd(1+q^{d})=\\
=f(x-3d)⋅q^{3d}+kd(1+q^{d}+q^{2d})\\
Generalization:\\
f(x)=q^{x}\cdot k(0)+k\cdot\lim_{d->0}{\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{x}{d}-1}{d\cdot q^{nd}}}\\
\boxed{f(x)=q^{x}\cdot k(0)+k\cdot\int_{0}^{x}{q^tdt}}
$$
All the properties of the classic Arithmetic-Geometric progression are met. Prove it yourself.
And this is a special case for the formula that I want.

Now, I will substitute k(x) and q(x) given above in my formula:
$$
q( x) =q_{0} \cdot q^{x}\\
k( x) =k\cdot x+k_{0}\\
\\
\frac{q( x+d)}{q( x)} =\frac{q_{0} \cdot q^{x+d}}{q_{0} \cdot q^{x}} =q^{d}\\
k( x+d) -k( x) =k\cdot ( x+d) +k_{0} -( k\cdot x+k_{0}) =kd\\
\\
f( x) =k( x) +q( x) \cdot \int _{0}^{x}\frac{k( t) \cdot q\prime ( t)}{q^{2}( t)} dt=\\
=k\cdot x+k_{0} +q_{0} \cdot q^{x} \cdot \int _{0}^{x}\frac{( k\cdot t+k_{0}) \cdot q_{0} \cdot q^{t} \cdot ln( q)}{q_{0}^{2} \cdot q^{2t}} dt=\\
=k\cdot x+k_{0} +q^{x} \cdot ln( q) \cdot \int _{0}^{x}\frac{( k\cdot t+k_{0})}{q^{t}} dt=\\
=k\cdot x+k_{0} +q^{x} \cdot ln( q) \cdot \left( k\cdot \int _{0}^{x}\frac{t}{q^{t}} dt+k_{0} \cdot \int _{0}^{x}\frac{1}{q^{t}} dt\right) =\\
=k\cdot x+k_{0} +q^{x} \cdot ln( q) \cdot \left( k\cdot \frac{q^{x} -x\cdot ln( q) -1}{ln^{2}( q) \cdot q^{x}} +k_{0} \cdot \frac{1-q^{-x}}{ln( q)}\right) =\\
=k\cdot x+k_{0} +q^{x} \cdot \left( k\cdot \frac{q^{x} -x\cdot ln( q) -1}{ln( q) \cdot q^{x}} +k_{0} \cdot \left( 1-q^{-x}\right)\right) =\\
=k\cdot x+k_{0} +k\cdot \frac{q^{x} -x\cdot ln( q) -1}{ln( q)} +k_{0} \cdot q^{x} -k_{0} \ =\\
=k\cdot \frac{q^{x} -1}{ln( q)} +k_{0} \cdot q^{x} =k( 0) \cdot q^{x} +k\cdot \int _{0}^{x} q^{t} dt
$$
And I've got the same result. So my formula should be ok.

Comment: For `k=0` it is the geometric progression formula. For `q=1` it is the arithmetic progression formula. And it works fine for all k and q as I want.